# Replacing non alphanumeric characters in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, utf-8

I'm trying something that has turned out truly annoying. I am a swede, and we have three characters that is somewhat unique (åäö ÅÄÖ). The script I am working on is network related so I need to replace these with a and o instead. That part is fairly straightforward

```
$A = $A.Replace('ä','a')
```

And so forth.

The problem turns out that if the 'script' is not saved in UTF-8 the characters can turn out in many different ways, for example:

```
å  = å
Ã¥ = å
ã¥ = å
```

And the latest problem turned out that it doesn't even recognise the character when it looks correct.

If the script must be saved as UTF-8 it's gonna be really hard to maintain. As, as soon as someone opens the script in an editor and that editor saves the script in a different encoding the script is broken.

So my question is. Is there any best praxis and/or way to define the script to use UTF-8 in the strings?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think the dupe target I chose would be a better approach. I can remove if it you truly disagree but it answers the title better than your proposed approach. Look at the high rated answer and not the marked answer.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for that link, was looking for it for some time.  The easiest way seems to be `'åäö ÅÄÖ'.Normalize("FormD") -replace '\p{M}'` returning `aao AAO`

Comment: Sorry for the double post. Been searching like crazy for a solution, but just couldn't find anything about this. Awesome magic there LotPings. It works great, just not sure HOW or WHY it works. If possible, please explain. I'm here to learn.